# Inner div element position

Tags: html, css

I need to display two div elements inside a parent div , something which looks like this

[image: Position of div elements]

And I tried something for this like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div >

<div style="background-color:red;display:inline-flex;">inner div 1</div>

<div style="background-color:yellow;display:inline-flex;">inner div 2 

<div style="background-color:yellow;">innermost div 1</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow;">innermost div 2 </div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And also some combinations , but nothing works for me , anyone please suggest on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with display:inline-block?

```
<div  style="background-color:green; padding:5px;" >

    <div style="background-color:red;padding:5px; display:inline-block;">inner div 1</div>

    <div style="background-color:yellow;padding:5px; display:inline-block;">inner div 2 

        <div style="background-color:blue;padding:5px;">innermost div 1</div>
        <div style="background-color:brown;padding:5px;">innermost div 2 </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try just adding divs and than use some `width`/`float: left` and other css to get in in right layout.

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.half {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.inner {
  margin: 2px 5px;
  height: 30px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  Div
  <br/>
  <div class="half">
    Div 1
  </div>
  <div class="half">
    Div 2
    <div class="inner">
      div 1
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      div 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are sereral problems with your code.

1. divs need a width and a height
2. if you use flex property you should know how it's working behind the scenes
3. why dont you just use position relative to the parent and top/right values ti bring your markup in shape?

i hope some of this tipps will help you. if not consider to ask more precise.

with best regards paul

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:170px">

<div style="background-color:red;float:left">inner div 1</div>

<div style="background-color:yellow;float:right; height:200px;padding-bottom:15px;">inner div 2 

<div style="background-color:yellow;height:100px">innermost div 1</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow;">innermost div 2 </div>


</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="child">
        <div>child</div>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">child</div>
            <div class="child">child</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent{
    display:flex;
    align-items:stretch;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
}
.column{
    flex-direction:column;
}
.child{
    flex:1 0;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

[**See DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/LaLhnkn1/)